# Query for friends events

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query for a user's facebook friends events using FQL. I've used the following query but haven't been succesful so far:

```
SELECT eid
FROM event
WHERE eid IN
    (SELECT eid
     FROM event_member
     WHERE UID IN
         (SELECT uid2
          FROM friend
          WHERE uid1 = Me()))
```

Any tip? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is even possible, you will have to authenticate with a specific permission to access your friends events. Search for "facebook api permissions"

Answer (score 1):

The query is fine (though you don't need `select eid from event` as `select eid from event_member` gives you the same data).  As Gil Birman says, you'll need the `friends_events` permission for this.

Comment: You're right. I was asking for the `friends_activities` permission instead of the `friends_events`.